# Assembly.LoadFrom works differently in .NET Core and .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have two `.csproj` projects, with the exact same source code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Assembly jsonAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\path\to\Newtonsoft.Json.dll");
        Type reflectionType = jsonAssembly.GetType("Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject");

        Console.Write("Types match: " + (reflectionType == typeof(JObject)));
        Console.Write("Typenames match: " + (reflectionType.FullName == typeof(JObject).FullName));

        JObject cast = (JObject)Activator.CreateInstance(reflectionType);
        Console.Write("Success!");
    }
}
```

Both `.csproj` files have an identical reference to Newtonsoft.Json:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
  <HintPath>C:\path\to\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The only difference between the two projects is that I created the first one using .NET Core 2.0, and the second one using .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Framework:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{A6D2C332-B60D-41F1-9983-DE10065973A1}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>ConsoleApp1</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ConsoleApp1</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <HintPath>C:\path\to\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Core:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <HintPath>C:\path\to\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I run the above code using .NET Core, I get the following response:

```
Types match: True
Typenames match: True
Success!
```

When I run the above code using .NET Framework, I get the following response:

```
Types match: False
Typenames match: True

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: [A]Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject cannot be cast to [B]Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
```

Why do .NET Framework and .NET Core work differently when loading assemblies via reflection?

Comment: What version of the Newtonsoft.Json.dll are you referencing? I've compiled your code in .NET Framework 4.6.1 and .NET Core 2.0. In both cases I get 'True' in the Types match. I the 12.0.1 version.

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1.  However, the package hasn't mattered in the past.  (It works with other packages)  I'll add my csproj files.

Comment: @HansPassant this is unrelated to Newtonsoft.JSON.  I can replicate it using any assembly.

Comment: Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/deployment/best-practices-for-assembly-loading

Answer (score 1):

The problem maybe is, that in .NET Framework you use 2 different assemblies (2 different files on disk). Try to run the .NET Framework project in debug mode and see where these types are coming from or add these lines.

```
Console.Write("Reflection type module: " + (reflectionType.Module.FullyQualifiedName));
Console.Write("Static type module: " + (typeof(JObject).Module.FullyQualifiedName));
```

Inspired by Walter Branson's answer, I did some research and found how some of the Load methods behave.

```
    /* Loads closest assembly given by FullName loaded by default, in this case it is from the same location as executable */
    Assembly jsonAssembly1 = Assembly.Load(@"Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed");

    /* Loads assembly exaclty from the file specified by path */
    Assembly jsonAssembly2 = Assembly.LoadFile($@"{pathToAssembly}\Newtonsoft.Json.dll");

    /* In NET.Framework loads same assembly as LoadFrom, but in .NET Core loads same assembly as Load */
    Assembly jsonAssembly3 = Assembly.LoadFrom($@"{pathToAssembly}\Newtonsoft.Json.dll");
```

Comment: You are correct: the .NETFramework is using 2 different assemblies (different paths).  I'm still not sure why this is the case, though.

Comment: When I run this for .NET Core project I see that both are from the same assembly and that is from the one where the executable is and it ignored the path I provided with Assembly.LoadFrom("...\Newtonsoft.Json.dll")

Comment: I found an issue that probably relates to this one https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/21982

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is occurring because the reference compare fails for .NET.  When you look at the objects there is a different handle in .NET.  When you look at the objects in core they both have same handle.

I think this occurs because you are loading the assembly from file.  Try loading the assembly by its fully qualified name.

```
Assembly jsonAssembly = Assebmly.Load("NewtonSoft.Json,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=30adfe6b2a6aeed")
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework one copies the .dll that you are referencing to its executable directory. So the loaded .dlls are actually different.

Try to change the path from `"C:\path\to\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"` in .NET Framework project to `"Newtonsoft.Json.dll"`, the result will be the same as in .NET Core one.